# TypeScript Ignoring Thunk- Unhandled Rejection (Error): Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I already do have Thunk in this application. The console logs showed everything working once, then everything stopped working. How do I get TypeScript to use Thunk?

Code:
Component including action creator as usual, also added interface for props to include Thunk action creator:

```
interface Props {
  ThunkAC: Function
}
```

AC throwing error:

```
export const GetItems = async (dispatch: Dispatch, accessToken: string) : Promise<any> => {
  console.log('AC called')
  const config = {
    headers: { 
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`
    }
  };
  return async (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
    const response = await axios.get(itemsUrl, config);
      dispatch({
        type: ActionTypes.getItems,
        payload: response.data.Items
      })

  }
}
```

index.tsx:

```
const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(thunk));


//Provider
const app = (
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  app,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Please tell me what is missing to use Thunk as the middleware to return a function in a TypeScript application.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone frustrated over this, you can't add Thunk in a TypeScript application just by adding explicit types to the Action Creators. It requires something called ThunkAction.

A lot of examples of it on GitHub.

Brief template in an Action Creator file:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { ThunkAction } from "redux-thunk";
import { Action } from 'redux';
import { initialState } from '../Reducers';
import { ActionTypes } from '../Actions/types';

export interface GetItem {
  type: ActionTypes.getItems;
  payload: ISavedItems;
}

export const items = (
  item: object
): ThunkAction<void, typeof initialState, null, Action<any>> => async dispatch => {
  const config = {
    headers: { 
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`
    }
  };
  const response = await axios.get(itemDB, config);
  dispatch<GetItem>({
    type: ActionTypes.getItems,
    payload: response.data.items
  })
};
```